# CASTING STRING TO BOOLEAN IN SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I HAVE A TABLE A

| ID | BOOLEAN |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | '70 <> 46 AND ('ID' = 'ID' OR 'ID' = 'PASSAPORT')' |

AND I WANT TO DO THIS

```
IF (SELECT BOOLEAN FROM A)
BEGIN
PRINT N'GOOD'
END
ELSE
PRINT N'BAD'
```

PD: IF YOU COPY THE ONLY THE FORMULA AND REPLACE IT INTO THE IF STATEMENT IT WORKS!

Comment: you need to use sql dynamic

Comment: You've tagged this with [tag:mysql] but `PRINT` is not supported by MySQL. Do you mean [tag:sql-server]?

Comment: What does "IN THE IF STATEMENT IT WORKS" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Dear Diego it seems the query is a Sql-Server code.
you need to use a dynamic query like this:

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

DECLARE @condition NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @condition = [BOOLEAN] FROM A

SET @query = 
'IF ('+@condition+')
BEGIN
PRINT N''GOOD''
END
ELSE
PRINT N''BAD'' '

EXECUTE(@query)
```